# Cannot rename column X which belongs to a clustering key

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have defined a table like this:

```
create or replace TABLE TEST_TABLE  cluster by LINEAR(ARTICLE, ORDER_DATE) (
    ORDER_DATE          DATE              
    ARTICLE             VARCHAR(1555) 
    note                VARCHAR(1555)
);
```

If I try to rename the column `ORDER_DATE`, I get an error that it cannot be renamed since it belongs to a clustering key. There is data inside this table that I do not want to get rid of. It is also not convenient to create a new table and copy the entire data into it since there is a lot of data.

Is there any way to temporarily remove the clustering key, rename it and add the key again?

or is there a way to do use a single statement that renames the column and changes the clustering col name at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Fastest solution: Drop the clustering key, rename the column and re-define the clustering key:

```
alter table TEST_TABLE rename column ORDER_DATE to ORDERDATE;
-- Cannot rename column 'ORDER_DATE' which belongs to a clustering key

alter table TEST_TABLE DROP CLUSTERING KEY;

alter table TEST_TABLE cluster by (ARTICLE, ORDERDATE);
```

This will not mess up the clustering of your table - Automatic Clustering doesn't need to recluster the table from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot rename a column which is a part of cluster key,
one option is to recreate the table with the new column name or create the table with out a cluster key and rename the column.

```
create or replace TABLE TEST_TABLE  --cluster by LINEAR(ARTICLE, ORDER_DATE)
(
    ORDER_DATE          DATE ,             
    ARTICLE             VARCHAR(1555) ,
    note                VARCHAR(1555)
);

alter table TEST_TABLE rename column ARTICLE to ARTICLE_new;
alter table TEST_TABLE rename column ORDER_DATE to ORDER_DATE_new;
```